# pass query string on url to filter media

Tags: query-posts, media, author-template, query-string

I have an author page which shows all uploaded media by that author. Each media can have tag1, tag2 or tag3. I would like to add an option where I can show on that same page only tag1 media without have to setup a new site structure. So I can up with the idea of using query strings.

My idea: passing a query string like http....url.../author/name?MediaTag=tag1

And use this in my query like `<?php query_posts('cat=1&author=' . $post->post_author . '&order=DESC&tag=' . $tag1 .'&posts_per_page=12' . '&paged=' . get_query_var('paged')); ?>`

and a check if there is no query string, it uses the one I'm using right now `<?php query_posts('cat=1&author=' . $post->post_author . '&order=DESC&posts_per_page=12' . '&paged=' . get_query_var('paged')); ?>`

Do I need to do anything else? Like catch the query string? Is this going to work? But never used this and any help is more than welcome. Maybe there is another way.

Comment: Btw - see this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the given url `http....url.../author/name?MediaTag=tag1`, below code may helpful...

```
if(isset($_GET['MediaTag']))  //It will check the value of MediaTag (from address bar after ?)
{
  $tag1 = $_GET['MediaTag'];  //Assigning value of MediaTag to the variable
  if($tag1)  //Checking if variable have some value or not
  {
    query_posts('cat=1&author=' . $post->post_author . '&order=DESC&tag=' .  $tag1 .'&posts_per_page=12' . '&paged=' . get_query_var('paged'));
  } else {
        query_posts('cat=1&author=' . $post->post_author . '&order=DESC&posts_per_page=12' . '&paged=' . get_query_var('paged'));
 }}
```

Comment: Hi Rishabh! Would you mind explaining how your code works?

Comment: Hi @Tim Malone Answer have been updated with explanation.

Comment: works like a charm Rishabh, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @AKNL I am glad it worked :)